# How to dispatch url with subdomain in Zend PHPUnit Controller test?

Tags: zend-framework, testing, subdomain, phpunit, dispatch

I want to test my controller which works on subdomain www.username.domain.com

The problem is when I dispatch in ControllerTestCase it throws Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception

---

routes.php:

```
$userRouter = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(':user.domain.com'));

$router->addRoute('user', $userRouter->chain(new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('',
                            array('controller' => 'user'))));
```

---

UserControllerTest:

```
require_once 'AbstarctControllerTestCase.php';

class UserControllerTest extends AbstarctControllerTestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->cleardb();
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function testRoute()
    {
        $this->dispatch('www.username.domain.com');
        $this->assertController('user');
    }
}
```

---

AbstarctControllerTestCase:

```
abstract class AbstarctControllerTestCase extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->bootstrap = array($this, 'appBootstrap');
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function appBootstrap()
    {
        chdir(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))));
        require 'application/test/controllerunit/routes.php';
        Zend_Session::start();
    }
(...)
}
```

Result:

```
PHPUnit 3.3.17 by Sebastian Bergmann.

F

Time: 1 second

There was 1 failure:

1) testRoute(UserControllerTest)
Failed asserting last controller used was "user"
```

When I dispatch normal URI like /login it work well but the problem is dispatching URLs with hostnames.

Any ideas?
Thank you all.

Comment: Is the router and route added to FrontController in tests too? Take a look at the source of `dispatch();` to see what data are used for dispatching (eg. host name).

Answer (score 2):

Did you try setting the $_SERVER variable in setup?

e.g.

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = 'www.username.domain.com';
```

and then call dispatch as per usual.

See - http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Worked for me.  It'd be nice if Zend_Controller_Request_HttpTestCase provided a setHost() method.

Answer (score 2):

Define `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` before calling `dispatch()` .

There is already a ticket with the same concern under http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-11680